# flowtype: "object literal could not decide which case to select" when using constants in redux actions

Tags: javascript, redux, flowtype

**EDIT**: [Here is a full GitHub repo](https://github.com/saadq/test-ignore) of a minimal example that shows the issue.

I have a simple Counter app. Here are my action creators:

**actions.js**

```
/**
 * @flow
 */

import { INCREMENT, DECREMENT } from '../constants'

type Action =
  | { type: 'INCREMENT' }
  | { type: 'DECREMENT' }

function increment(): Action {
  return {
    type: INCREMENT
  }
}

function decrement(): Action {
  return {
    type: DECREMENT
  }
}

export { increment, decrement }
export type { Action }
```

Currently, I'm getting an error in both the `increment` and `decrement` functions which states that **object literal Could not decide which case to select union type**.

To fix these errors, I can change `type: INCREMENT` to `type: 'INCREMENT'` and change `type: DECREMENT` to `type: 'DECREMENT'`. However, I'm going to be using this constant in multiple places (like the reducer), so I was hoping to be able to just import the constant and use it there. Is this not the way it's done in flowtype?

For clarity, here are the rest of the files:

**constants.js**

```
/**
 * @flow
 */

const INCREMENT: 'INCREMENT' = 'INCREMENT'
const DECREMENT: 'DECREMENT' = 'DECREMENT'

export {
  INCREMENT,
  DECREMENT
}
```

**reducer.js**

```
/**
 * @flow
 */

import { INCREMENT, DECREMENT } from '../constants'
import type { Action } from '../actions'

type State = number

function counter(state: State = 0, action: Action): State {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INCREMENT:
      return state + 1

    case DECREMENT:
      return state - 1

    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default counter
```

Edit: Here is a detailed error log

```
src/actions/counter.js:12
              v
 12:   return {
 13:     type: INCREMENT
 14:   }
       ^ object literal. Could not decide which case to select
 11: function increment(): Action {
                           ^^^^^^ union type
  Case 1 may work:
    8:   | { type: 'INCREMENT' }
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ object type
  But if it doesn't, case 2 looks promising too:
    9:   | { type: 'DECREMENT' }
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ object type
  Please provide additional annotation(s) to determine whether case 1 works (or consider merging it with case 2):
   13:     type: INCREMENT
                 ^^^^^^^^^ identifier `INCREMENT`

src/actions/counter.js:18
              v
 18:   return {
 19:     type: DECREMENT
 20:   }
       ^ object literal. Could not decide which case to select
 17: function decrement(): Action {
                           ^^^^^^ union type
  Case 1 may work:
    8:   | { type: 'INCREMENT' }
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ object type
  But if it doesn't, case 2 looks promising too:
    9:   | { type: 'DECREMENT' }
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ object type
  Please provide additional annotation(s) to determine whether case 1 works (or consider merging it with case 2):
   19:     type: DECREMENT
                 ^^^^^^^^^ identifier `DECREMENT`
```

Comment: Export each of the constant separately from your counter : `export const INCREMENT = 'INCREMENT'`. And also re-exporting them in your action.js is not necessary.

Comment: That doesn't seem to resolve the issue, but why would it? Both my method of exporting and the method you mentioned are valid ways of exporting things from a module. As for your comment about re-exporting them, I don't think I am. I'm just exporting the action creators there.

Comment: You say `tried adding types to these constants`, what specifically did you try? I think you'd need `const INCREMENT: 'INCREMENT' = 'INCREMENT'`.

Comment: Sorry, probably should have mentioned that. I've actually already tried `const INCREMENT: 'INCREMENT' = 'INCREMENT'` as well as `const INCREMENT: string = 'INCREMENT'`.

Comment: I've also added the detailed error message at the very bottom of my post in case it's any help.

Comment: I've added a GitHub repo to the top of my original post in case anyone wants to try it out. Just run `npm install` and then `npm start` and go to `http://localhost:3000`. It's very strange because if I create the constant variables in my `actions.js` file instead of importing them, the errors go away.

Comment: I downloaded your repo, installed & started, but I can't see any error - with or without the quotes.

Answer (score 5):

Try to add `typeof` into you action declaration:

```
type Action = 
  | { type: typeof INCREMENT } 
  | { type: typeof DECREMENT }
```

[try flow here](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAkgOQMICUCiBZNCAqAuGAckVU2x0JgF4iT0tdCBuAKFElgBE1SH8juvcpRqFB9YaxZQAngAcApjACCwKAEtw1GCxgwAPjADeMWYoJmFIAGbxkE3DAC+OvYZOWL8q7fFlHTiws1gCuYGqaYDDq4QBOCgC2CmBQABQAlASqGlpGujDxUCGxUXl6ep52Qrj5gYHBYRFaACYKwPFJKRlZTaX5hcV95abeBH58tSxOQA)

Also you can use `$Keys`

```
const ActionTypes = {
  INCREMENT: 'INCREMENT',
  DECREMENT: 'DECREMENT'
}

type Action = { type: $Keys<typeof ActionTypes> }
```

[this looks less verbose](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAgsKBLcAVAngBwKYRgXhgG8AoGGASQDkBhAJQFEBZBq1ALhgHJr7nXUXADRkYAEQZ8WbTlwlSBXEgF8SJKFmzxEKMAWIwNOTgBIA0tnQQAPEewgAZtuRpNEAHwxlMNQ4CuYDrgMEiBAE7YALbYYFAAFACUnAgueqTkEVB+YWmi5HbJQWAYOBAAdLyM0qiiqqok-oGpMAAm2MAR0bGJhc3pMJnZueT5mr26Jbhl8lUCtSpAA)

additional info here: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2377

Comment: Hmm, so it seems using the second example with the `ActionTypes` does fix the problem. However, the first example with the `typeof` doesn't do anything. But why is adding this extra information necessary? I'm mainly confused why my code works if I create the constants inside the `actions.js` file instead of importing them. I will accept your answer within a couple of days though if there are no better replies and award you the bounty.